# Unable to return home to China with my Chinese spouse

Tags: europe, china, covid-19, spouses

Our residence is in China. My spouse is a Chinese national but I am not (I am a UK/US dual-national). We have been visiting relatives in Europe, which is only a temporary residence for *all* parties involved. Our relatives are leaving Europe for a new destination. We don't really have the means to stay any longer.

My spouse is allowed to return to our country of origin (China) but I am currently barred. My spouse doesn't have any travel permits for either the UK or the US; past applications for both territories have also previously been denied. What options do we have? We're looking for an option that doesn't have entail separation.

Comment: There is nothing barring you personally from traveling to either the UK or the US?

Comment: I guess you are looking for a travel option that will let you two stay together. Can you clarify that?

Comment: You should contact the nearest Chinese consulate or embassy. Visas issued after the ban comes into effect will be valid, and there are probably exceptions for immediate family of Chinese nationals.

Comment: @jcaron I don't see an exception for spouses in Timatic. Contacting the consulate is probably best at this time.

Comment: Do you reside in China?  If you have been residing, even perhaps for as short a period as three months, in an EU or Schengen country rather than just visiting, your wife can accompany you to the UK under EU freedom of movement law, by virtue of the [Surinder Singh](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/surinder-singh) ruling.  (The "centre of life" test has recently been ruled unlawful; the linked page has not yet been updated.)

Comment: I understand why you would not want to be separated but I wonder if, given the economic fallout of lockdowns around the world, you should consider where you and your wife will each best be in a position to support yourselves and/or access any government-provided financial assistance? If you were both able enter the UK by virtue of the Surinder Singh route, for example, where would you live and what income would you have?

Comment: Go to Wikipedia. There’s a list for visa requirements for Chinese citizens. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Chinese_citizens.  There’s another visa requirements for USA citizens. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_United_States_citizens Marry the two lists to choose countries which are visa free for both. Then individually check each of those countries to eliminate those with bans for non-nationals. Voila, you have your options!!! Good luck

Comment: @user 56513 Much easier to do via https://www.passportindex.org/comparebyPassport.php

Comment: In fact, not even Chinese citizens are allowed to return to China in general, at the moment. Not only that international flights serving China have been dramatically cut down, it is also required that anyone boarding those flights, **including Chinese citizens**, be pre-approved by Chinese authorities before boarding. One would only be approved for emergencies, approved essential activities, or (for Chinese citizens) if their legal status in another country is expiring and cannot be extended . **Forget about returning to China right now**.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.